# Axios in React: GET Request works, PUT returns unauthrorized

Tags: reactjs, axios

I get a very strange behaviour with Axios. I want to perform a PUT request, but I get a 401 (unauthorized)

`"PUT /update_todo/62a4cb75d7aa95ab6a70f202 HTTP/1.1" 401 Unauthorized`

FastAPI

```
@app.put("/update_todo/{id}")
async def update(id: str, user=Depends(manager)):
    item = await update_todo(id, user)
    return Todo(**item)
```

React

```
  const update_todo = (id) => {
    axios
      .put(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/update_todo/${id}`, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      })
      .then(() => {
        getAllTodos(token);
      });
  };
```

When I change my endpoints to `get`, everything works fine and the error disappears.

`"GET /update_todo/62a4cb75d7aa95ab6a70f202 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK`

In my backend I set the following:

```
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins= ["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

This behaviour is weird, I would normally expect that every endpoint works the same way. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: First, did u use a tool like postman to check if the API works correctly?

Comment: @IsuruPerera: Yes, I used curl, everything works fine. And like I wrote, changing the endpoint from `PUT` to `GET` also works. The only change is PUT vs GET

Comment: You can see the exact request that you are sending in your web browser's devtools panel, Network tab, and even "copy as curl".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

`PUT` expects data as second argument.

```
  const update_todo = (id) => {
    axios
      .put(
        `http://127.0.0.1:8000/update_todo/${id}`,
        {},
        {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
        }
      )
      .then(() => {
        getAllTodos(token);
      });
  };
```

Adding an empty dictionary as data solved it.